# jQuery changing the button title in Boostrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I try using the same type of jQuery for changing the panel code but it didn't work. I am not sure what I am missing here. The button is to open a dropdown menu and changing the title in button allows the screen reader user know that the menu is open or closed.
Here is the code:

```
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" id="menu_button" role="menu" class="navbar-toggle pull-left" title="Menu button closed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar" >
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button> 
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">News and Information</a>
      </div>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page A</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page B</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Page C <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Page C - 1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Page C - 2</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Page C - 3</a></li>        
                </ul>        
            </li>
          </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

jQuery

```
    <script>
    $('.navbar-header').on('shown.bs.navbar-header', function(){
        $(this).parent().find(".navbar-toggle").attr('title', 'dropdown menu open');
        }).on('hidden.bs.navbar', function(){
        $(this).parent().find(".navbar-toggle").attr('title', 'dropdown menu closed');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you add a fiddle to demonstrate?

Comment: You mean, something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/sd9x5tr4/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JS code is wrong:

1. You have to attach an event handler to `.navbar-collapse` (not to `.navbar-header`).
2. There is no `shown.bs.navbar-header`. Use `shown.bs.collapse` instead.

Use this:

```
$('.navbar-collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function() {
  $(this).parent().find(".navbar-toggle").attr('title', 'dropdown menu open');
}).on('hidden.bs.collapse', function() {
  $(this).parent().find(".navbar-toggle").attr('title', 'dropdown menu closed');
});
```

### [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gajZLm)

By the way, Bootstrap uses `aria-expanded` to indicate state of collapsible element, so you do not have to use this.

> When authors use collapsible content, for example, to hide navigation menus or lists of content, the triggering link or button should indicate to screen reader users whether the collapsable content below is in the expanded or in the collapsed state. The aria-expanded attribute is used for this purpose.